# Can 'update' attribute update two components simultanously?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a question. Is that possible to update two components at a time?
I am trying a code like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="pickList">
    <p:panel  rendered="#{customCalender.visible}" widgetVar="searchTableBox">

    //Some codes.....

        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" update="pickList" actionListener="#{customCalender.closeList}" style="background:#25A6E1;color:red;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;font-size:10px;border-radius:4px;" />
        <p:commandButton value="Save" update="custDataTablePanel" actionListener="#{customCalender.saveTargetList}" style="background:#25A6E1;color:red;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;font-size:10px;border-radius:4px;"/>
   </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
....
.....
<h:panelGroup  id="custDataTablePanel">
   <p:panel rendered="#{customCalender.dataTableVisible}">
..
..
   </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Now I want when I click on the `Save` button it hides the `<h:panelGroup id="pickList">` and displays the `<h:panelGroup id="custDataTablePanel">` so I have two boolean values to control their visibility. but I need to update two of these panels. One I did with `update="custDataTablePanel"` it displays the data table after the button click.(in the method `saveTargetList` I updated the visibility of the `custDataTablePanel` to true.) but cant manage to hide the panel `pickList`.

So I was wandering is there any way to hide and show these two panels in one button click.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use many elements in the update attribute separated by a space

```
<p:commandButton update="element1 element2"/>
```

also you can update the whole form by using `update="@form"`

Comment: I have tried this `<p:commandButton update="element1 element2"/>` but in that case my command button is not displayed.

Comment: it worked now..Thank you.May be I was doing it in a wrong way before!! anyway Thanks.. :)

Comment: Thanks.. i dont use primefaces, but Your answer put me on right track.. in selectOneMenu render attribute, works the same way, so just putted all components ids separated by space there and bum. :)